# Conditionally link i386 or armv7 depending on need

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, cordova

I have an Xcode project that is currently using Apache Cordova's static library. I'd like to be able to run this on the simulator as well as on iOS devices. I've currently added the two different libraries to the Xcode project (one that supports i386 and one that supports armv7), but I can't seem to figure out how I would tell the linker which one to link. Up until now I've been using "Other Linker Flags" to tell it the path to the Cordova library.

How would I tell the linker the version of the library it should be using?

Comment: Why don't you lipo the two together into a fat file and let the linker decide which to use based on what arch you're currently building for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out

What you have to do is add the two different static libraries to the project. Then remove them from the normal build phases and possibly your source file search locations underneath build settings. Then you have to go to other linker flags, click on debug or release and click on "Add Build Setting" -> "Conditional Build Setting" in the bottom right. It will pop up an new build setting for which you can specify the platform underneath which it should be linked in. You have to add the two architectures for both debug and release if you want it to work.

Check out [Apple's](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/Adding%20a%20Conditional%20Build%20Setting.html) tutorial.